# Ratio between the surface areas of two cones, given the areas of the bases.

Tags: geometry

If you have a cone with a base of 10 square cm and another cone with a base of 5 square cm, what is the ratio between the surface areas, given that the angle of the sloped sides is 60 degrees. When I calculated the two areas using trigonometry I found that the ratio was 2, however, intuitively I thought the area scale factor would be the linear scale factor (2) squared, giving a ratio of 4. Where is the flaw in my logic?

[image]

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the details of your calculation.

Comment: Well its not the calculation I am having difficult with, I am pretty sure the ratio is 2, however, why isn’t the ratio 4 (because I thought that if the lengths double, then the area quadruples, but that doesn’t seem to be the case, and I am struggling to understand why).

Comment: The ratio IS 4: you must have made some error in your calculation.

Comment: @aretino, could you check my working, I have edited the original question?

Comment: In the "S.A." line, it looks like you are trying to get the area from $\pi r \times x$.  The correct expression is $\pi r \times (r+x)$.

Comment: @Aretino no, the calculations are good.  If the areas of the bases have doubled and height scaled up proportionally, then lateral area will double, too.

Comment: @DougM Ah, OK: I misread the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You incorrectly stated that the linear scale factor is 2. Instead, the linear scale is $\sqrt2$. This is because the ratio of the two given base areas is $\frac{10}{5}=2$, which translates into the linear ratio of $\sqrt2$.

Thus, the area ratio of the two cones is 2.

Comment: Given how quickly you picked up two points (one mine), I suspect I was not the only person who was writing up the same thing when you posted.

Comment: Oh yes, of course! Thanks